# How to add more code to the child class constructor while passing arguments to parent class constructor?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

Child class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace Game
{
    public class Warrior:Inhabitant
    {
        public Warrior(string name,int age):base(name,age)
        {
            private bool mobility;
            private bool immortality;
        }
    }
}
```

Now the parent class:

```
public class Inhabitant {

     private string name;
     private int age;

    public Inhabitant(string name,int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
```

This code worked in Java. I can't understand why it's not working here.

Comment: What error are you getting? You may want to make your private fields protected if you want to access them from the derived class.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working?

Comment: You will have to define what you mean by "not working". This code should assign the name and age values. Will this compile? Have you set breakpoints or written unit tests to verify that the name and age vars are what you expect? If you can, show your error, and we can help more.

Comment: You just cannot use access modifiers in method or constructor variables. Remove the `private` from both `mobility` and `immortality` and everything should be fine.

Comment: You are defining attributes inside the constructor of Warrior, that's not legal. Move that out. You can assign them there or have any other kind of code you want.

Comment: } expected (CS1513) - C:\Users\DELL PC\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\HelloWorld\Game\Warrior.cs:16,4

Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected (CS1022) - C:\Users\DELL PC\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\HelloWorld\Game\Warrior.cs:21

These are the errors

Comment: @lukegv yeah.it is working now.can you tell me why that happened?

Comment: You can simply use access modifiers (`private`, `protected`, `public`) only on class members and not on variables in methods. Method variables are always "private" to the method scope. Since a variable is not supposed to have a access modifier, the compiler reports it as an error.

Comment: @Fredy Treboux
Yeah.When I moved out it worked.but I want those attributes to be established in the warrior when he is created.so they have to be put inside the constructor right?
I'm new to c#. This type of coding normally works in Java

Comment: No, this is not correct. The only allowed variable modifier in Java is `final`. The above code would not have worked in Java, too.

Comment: Thanks everyone!!

Comment: @lukegv Yeah.I made a huge mistake when copy pasting the java code to c#. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare private fields and initialize them in constructor

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
namespace Game
{
    public class Warrior:Inhabitant
    {
        // declare private fields
        private bool mobility;
        private bool immortality;

        public Warrior(string name,int age, bool mobility, bool immortality):base(name,age)
        {
            // initialize
            this.mobility=mobility;
            this.immortality=immortality;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was useful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare your members *outside* the constructor:

   ```
   public class Warrior:Inhabitant
   {
       private bool mobility;
       private bool immortality;

       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Pass parameters to your new constructor:

   ```
   public class Warrior:Inhabitant
   {
       private bool mobility;
       private bool immortality;

       public Warrior(string name,int age, bool mobility, bool immortablity) : base(name,age) // base call as usual
       {
           // set properties
           this.mobility = mobility;
           this.immortability = immortability;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful info

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can not declare any variable as private inside constructor or method of a class.

Change Warrior class as following and it should resolve the issue.

```
public class Warrior:Inhabitant
{
    private bool mobility;
    private bool immortality;
    public Warrior(string name,int age):base(name,age)
    {

    }
}
```

if they are the variables local to the constructor then they should be declared without access modifiers.

```
public class Warrior:Inhabitant
{
    public Warrior(string name,int age):base(name,age)
    {
        bool mobility;
        bool immortality;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you cant use access modifiers inside constructor. Try:

```
public Warrior(string name,int age):base(name,age)
{
   bool mobility;
   bool immortality;
}
```

The above is syntactically correct , but does not do anything semantically,  since mobility and immortality live only inside the constructor. Probably you want sth like:

```
public class Warrior:Inhabitant
{
       private bool mobility;
       private bool immortality;
       public Warrior(string name,int age):base(name,age)
       {
            this.mobility=false; //example case
            this.immortality=true; //example case
       }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I actually made a huge mistake. My bad! Sorry